# how to resize two divs using the separiting line between them?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have two divs separated vertically. and I need to resize both of them using the separating line between them. I have gap in the right handed div and it get worse on resize. please help me to get rad this unwanted gap and make resizing possible using separating line between them.

I have an example at [codepen](https://codepen.io/MedooEgy/pen/wvMXezO)

```js
$( function() {
  
      $("#side").resizable({
       handles: 'e'
    });
  
      $("#editor").resizable()
      .sortable({
        items: ".item"
      }).disableSelection();
  
      $(".item")
        .mousedown
      (function(){ $(this).css('cursor','grabbing'); })
        .draggable
      ({ 
        revert: "invalid", 
        helper: "clone",
        connectToSortable: "#editor" 
      });
  
});
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  position: fixed;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}

#editor {
  float: left;
  width: 72%;
  height: 100vh;
  background:#9999;
  text-align: right;
}

#side{
  float: left;
  width:26%;
  min-width: 130px;
  max-width: 260px;
  height: 100vh;
  background:#708090;
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  color:yellow;
  cursor: move;
}

.item{
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  border-radius: .4em;
  background-color: white;
  color: #000;
  padding:12px;
  margin:10px;
  display: inline-block;  
  align-content:center;
}
.item:hover{
  cursor:grab;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css"/>


<div id="container">
  
<div id="side">
  <h3 id="title">I'm resizable</h3>
    <i class="fa fa-align-center item"> Section 1</i>
    <i class="fa fa-align-center item"> Section 2</i>
    <i class="fa fa-align-center item"> Section 3</i>
    <i class="fa fa-align-center item"> Section 4</i>
    <i class="fa fa-align-center item"> Section 5</i>
    <i class="fa fa-align-center item"> Section 6</i>

</div>
  
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
  <h3 id="title">I'm editable</h3>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this is using flexbox IMO. Here's the changes to the css that made it all work:

```
#container {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  display: flex;
}

#editor {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  background:#9999;
  text-align: right;
}

#side{
  min-width: 130px;
  max-width: 260px;
  height: 100vh;
  background:#708090;
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  color:yellow;
  cursor: move;
}

.item{
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  border-radius: .4em;
  background-color: white;
  color: #000;
  padding:12px;
  margin:10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item:hover{
  cursor:grab;
}
```

You could probably clean it up even more with some of the height stuff but here's the basics anyway :)

I'd highly recommend getting good at Flexbox, it makes life working with CSS sooooo much easier. [Flexbox Summary](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks bro, I appreciate your comprehensive answer.